# Braintree: Sale and subscription in a single transaction possible?

Tags: php, sdk, transactions, subscription, braintree

I need to process both the sale and the subscription in a single transaction. Is it possible in braintree?

The user should not be charged twice. That's important.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I find your question a little unclear. Are you asking how to charge a transaction and then, separately, charge for a subscription? Or just how to create a subscription, which starts charging the customer right away?

If the second, the customer will be charged automatically when [creating a subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php) unless you [set a start date](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php#set-start-date).

Comment: I need to create a subscription and a single transaction with different price in one click but both should have a single transaction Id. Is it possible with braintree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do by using a [subscription add-on](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/add-on/php) that lasts for [1 billing cycle](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/add-on/php#number_of_billing_cycles).